# lpi is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error

Tags: runtime-error, windows-embedded

I've the following problem running an a certain application built using Visual Studio 2010. I got the following Error Message:

"x.lpi is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact the system administrator or the software vendor for support".

The application is running on a Microsoft Windows Embedded 7 (32-bit) but the application is built on a normal PC under Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit).

Note: "x" is the file name.
Is there any fix for this problem?

Comment: Do what the error message says: recompile.